# Startup and shutdown issues after Fedup from Fedora 20 -> 21 -> 22

Tags: fedora, grub2

After running fedup to upgrade from Fedora 20 to 21, and then to Fedora 22, I have been experiencing issues with startup and shutdown.

On reboot, I get the 3 versions on my Grub list. When I select the Grub option for Fedora 22, things look normal up to the login screen. Once I enter my credentials, they clear, but the system hangs only showing me the login background; waiting for several minutes makes no difference, system is stuck.

To solve this, I then hard reboot, and select the old Fedora 20 option in the Grub menu. When I login, everything works, and Fedora 22 loads correctly.

For shutdown, the system stays stuck in the Plymouth screen and does not power down, only by pressing the power button can I achieve this.

I suspect these issues might be related, maybe not? Anyone have some pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you execute all the [Cleaning Up Post Upgrade](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp#Cleaning_Up_Post_Upgrade) steps?

Comment: Yes, I've ran those steps. I believe it might be kernel related?
When I select "3.19.8-100.fc20.x86_64" things work fine, but when selecting one of the 4.0.x options, not able to boot the system after the login screen.
Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if some of your system-wide `/etc/...` files or individual account files (e.g., `~/.config, ~/.gnome*`) need to be updated and/or recreated.  If you create a new account, does its login, etc., operate normally?

Comment: Can you try uncommenting `#WaylandEnable=false` (remove the `#`) in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, I tried adding a new user, but it did not help.

Comment: @mattdm, I uncommented that line, but upon login my screen turned black, not even a background present anymore. I had to reboot and select the 3.19 kernel to be able to login and re-comment that.
However, that got me thinking. At the login screen there is a small gear icon to select the desktop. I tried Gnome classic, same issue. When I tried the "Gnome on Wayland" option: success, able to login and function properly with the 4.0.x kernels! :)
Though it still feels like there is something wrong with my system if the default Gnome option won't load.

Comment: With regards to the shutdown issue, clicked esc on plymouth screen reveals that the system is stuck with this message: 
"A stop job is running for Manage Sound Card State (restore and store) (1min 37s / 3min)"
I'll try and Google around for that sound issue, but I'm still totally stumped with the login issue.
Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: What graphics card and driver?

Comment: VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1603
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon